# session form data across multiple pages and insert into mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

can someone help me please, im trying to submit a form over 3 pages. theres 3 text area fields in each and im using session start to echo the form data other the pages.

so then at the end all i have to do is echo out the form data and insert it into the mysql table ptb_registrations.

for some reason though its not working and im getting the error updating database error. i have been working on this for a few hours im sorry to say and i can not figure it out. please can someone help me and show me where i might be going wrong.

page 1:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<form class="" method="post" action="register_p2.php">
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" />
<input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" />
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"  />
<input type="submit" value="Next >"  />
</form>
```

page 2:

```
<?php
session_start();
// other php code here

$_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
$_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
?>
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="register_p3.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" >
<input type="text" id="date_of_birth" name="date_of_birth" placeholder="D.O.B 10/02/1990" />
<input type="text" id="number" name="number" placeholder="Mobile Number" />
<input type="text" id="confirm" name="confirm" placeholder="Are You a UK resident?"  />
<input type="submit" value="Next >"  />
</form>
```

page 3:

```
<?php
session_start();
// other php code here

$_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
$_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
$_SESSION['dat_of_birth'] = $date_of_birth;
$_SESSION['number'] = $number;
?>

<form class="" method="post" action="register_p4.php">
<input type="text" id="display_name" name="date_of_birth" placeholder="Display Name" />
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
<input type="password" id="password2" name="password2" placeholder="Password (Confirm)"  />
<input type="submit" value="Next >"  />
</form>
```

page 4: (mysql function)

```
<?php
session_start();
// other php code here

$_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
$_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
$_SESSION['dat_of_birth'] = $date_of_birth;
$_SESSION['number'] = $number;
$_SESSION['display_name'] = $display_name;
$_SESSION['password'] = $password;
?>

<?php
////// SEND TO DATABASE


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Database Constants
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "");
define("DB_NAME", "database");

// 1. Create a database connection
$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

// 2. Select a database to use
$db_select = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$connection);
if (!$db_select) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$query="INSERT INTO ptb_registrations (ID,
first_name,
last_name,
email,
date_of_birth,
contact_number,
display_name,
password
 )
VALUES('NULL',
'".$first_name."',
'".$last_name."',
'".$email."',
'".$date_of_birth."',
'".$number."',
'".$display_name."',
'".$password."'
)";
mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database');
?>
<?php
function confirm_query($result_set) {
                if (!$result_set) {
                    die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
                }
        }
function get_user_id() {
    global $connection;
    global $email;
    $query = "SELECT *
                FROM ptb_registrations
                WHERE email = \"$email\"
                ";
        $user_id_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
        confirm_query($user_id_set);
        return $user_id_set;
        }
?>
<?php
$user_id_set = get_user_id();
while ($user_id = mysql_fetch_array($user_id_set)) {
    $cookie1 = "{$user_id["id"]}";
    setcookie("ptb_registrations", $cookie1, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */

}
?>

<?php include ('includes/send_email/reg_email.php'); ?>

<? ob_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: Through $_POST['First_Name'] you will have to catch the value in second page instead of referring it as variable

Comment: Where did you learn to do it this way? This looks like it's full of [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that would make it extremely hazardous to put this anywhere near the internet.

Comment: If i had to guess about the database error - don't supply an ID in the insert. Take out the ID and the "null".

Comment: use $_POST[] instead of only $variabale_name.

Answer (score 2):

> please can someone help me and show me where i might be going wrong.

Your code itself is just horrible. **Because**:

1) You mix session and database responsibilities

2) You use `mysql_query()` for queries you do not expect a result-set. For `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` queries should be used `mysql_unbuffered_query()`

3) You do not escape values using `mysql_real_escape_string()` so that you're vulnerable to SQL injection

4) You use procedural code and global state

5) You use deprecated `mysql_*` functions instead of `PDO` or `MySQLi`

6) You use string concatenation instead of `sprintf()`, here:

```
 )
 VALUES(
    '".$first_name."',
    '".$last_name."',
    '".$email."',
    '".$date_of_birth."',
    '".$number."',
    '".$display_name."',
    '".$password."'
```

7) You do not validate anything in `$_SESSION` and `$_POST`. What if you have set the variables and they do not exist?

8) Your query validation is wrong, here: `confirm_query($result_set) {..`

I'd better stop here.

So instead of coding this way, you'd really separate responsibilities.

For session, it should look like this:

File `session.php`

```
function seesion_init(){
   if ( session_id() == '' ){
     return session_start();
   } else {
     return true;
   }
}

function session_set(array $values){
  foreach($values as $key => $val){
     $_SESSION[$key] = $val;
  }
}

/**
 * It will give you a confidence that you get an existing value
 * @param string $key
 */
function session_get($key){
    if ( isset($_SESSION[$key]) ){
         return $_SESSION[$key];
    } else {
       throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('Accessed to non-existing session variable %s', $key));
    }
}
```

File: `dbconnection.php`

```
<?php

define('HOST', '...');
define('USER', '...');
...


function connect(){

   if ( ! mysql_connect(...) ){
      die('...');
   }

   if ( ! mysql_select_db('DB_NAME_HERE') ){
       die('...');
   }
}


function query($query){
  return mysql_query($query); //<- Should only be used for SELECT queries
}


function ub_query($query){
   return mysql_unbuffered_query($query); // <- Should only be used for INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE queries
}

function fetch($result){
  return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}
```

File: `users.php`

```
require_once('dbconnection.php');

connect();

/**
 * Returns user id by his username
 * 
 * @return array on success
 *         FALSE if email does not exists  
 */
function get_user_id_by_email($email) {

   $query = sprintf("SELECT `id` FROM `ptb_registrations` WHERE `email` = '$email' LIMIT 1", mysql_real_escape_string($email));

   $result = ub_query($query);

   if ( $result ){
      return fetch($result);
   } else {
      return false;
   }

}
```

and so on. The concept here is to separate responsibilities for each script and then use the "part" you need.

**Back to the original question**

You want to insert a value into the table? Then validate this value firstly. The problem is that you do not do that. Nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

In `page2.php` you need set `session` as below.

because `$first_name, etc..` did not declared.

**page2.php**

```
$_SESSION['first_name'] = $_POST['first_name'];
$_SESSION['last_name'] = $_POST['last_name'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
```

**page3.php**

```
$_SESSION['dat_of_birth'] = $_POST['date_of_birth'];
$_SESSION['number'] = $_POST['number'];
```

**page4.php**

```
$_SESSION['display_name'] = $_POST['display_name'];
$_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
```

in page4.php do one more variables declaration.

```
$first_name = $_SESSION['first_name'];
$last_name = $_SESSION['last_name'];
$email = $_SESSION['email']; etc...
```

then store it in database.

Comment: do i need to add $_POST to page 3 aswel? or just page 2

Comment: ok cool and anything to add on page 4? i have removed the id and null on page 4 dunno if this helps?

Comment: ok did all of that and still getting the error updating database error message :(

Comment: try mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error()); and tell me what error you are getting..

Comment: i get this error: Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ptb1/includes/mod_register/mod_member/register_p4.php:18) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ptb1/includes/mod_register/mod_member/register_p4.php on line 19
Error updating database

Comment: put ob_start(); before session_start(); and ob_flush(); at end.

Comment: i dont have ob_start on page 4 or ob_flush

Comment: ok did that on page 4 and still got same error its not getting the values for some reason

Comment: why don't you make a common.php file in which database connecion and session declaration is held and then call it to every page....

Comment: i have and have attached it now but its not inserting the values properly its not the connection thats the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice, this whole script but I believe your SQL error is because you are supplying an ID as null. ID is probably an integer and most likely auto increment. Do this instead:

```
$query="INSERT INTO ptb_registrations (
    first_name,
    last_name,
    email,
    date_of_birth,
    contact_number,
    display_name,
    password
 )
 VALUES(
    '".$first_name."',
    '".$last_name."',
    '".$email."',
    '".$date_of_birth."',
    '".$number."',
    '".$display_name."',
    '".$password."'
 )";
```

Answer (score 0):

Pge 1:

```
<form class="" method="post" action="register_p2.php">
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" />
<input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" />
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"  />
<input type="submit" value="Next >"  />
</form>
```

No need of session_start here

Page2:

```
<?php
session_start();
// other php code here

$_SESSION['first_name'] = $_POST['first_name'];
$_SESSION['last_name'] = $_POST['last_name'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
?>
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="register_p3.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" >
<input type="text" id="date_of_birth" name="date_of_birth" placeholder="D.O.B 10/02/1990" />
<input type="text" id="number" name="number" placeholder="Mobile Number" />
<input type="text" id="confirm" name="confirm" placeholder="Are You a UK resident?"  />
<input type="submit" value="Next >"  />
</form>
```

Added $_POST

Page 3:

```
<?php
session_start();
// other php code here


$_SESSION['dat_of_birth'] = $_POST['date_of_birth'];
$_SESSION['number'] = $_POST['number'];
?>

<form class="" method="post" action="register_p4.php">
<input type="text" id="display_name" name="date_of_birth" placeholder="Display Name" />
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
<input type="password" id="password2" name="password2" placeholder="Password (Confirm)"  />
<input type="submit" value="Next >"  />
</form>
```

Added $_POST `$_SESSION['first_name'] = $_POST['first_name'];`

No need to add this section again in page3 :

```
$_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
$_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
```

Page 4:

```
<?php
session_start();
// other php code here

$first_name = $_SESSION['first_name'];
$last_name  = $_SESSION['last_name'];
$email      = $_SESSION['email'];
$date_of_birth = $_SESSION['dat_of_birth'] ;
$number    =$_SESSION['number'];
$display_name = $_SESSION['display_name'];
$password  = $_SESSION['password'];
?>

<?php
////// SEND TO DATABASE


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Database Constants
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "");
define("DB_NAME", "database");

// 1. Create a database connection
$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

// 2. Select a database to use
$db_select = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$connection);
if (!$db_select) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$query="INSERT INTO ptb_registrations (ID,
first_name,
last_name,
email,
date_of_birth,
contact_number,
display_name,
password
 )
VALUES('NULL',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($first_name)."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($last_name)."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($date_of_birth)."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($number)."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($display_name)."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."'
)";
mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database');
?>
<?php
function confirm_query($result_set) {
                if (!$result_set) {
                    die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
                }
        }
function get_user_id() {
    global $connection;
    global $email;
    $query = "SELECT *
                FROM ptb_registrations
                WHERE email = \"$email\"
                ";
        $user_id_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
        confirm_query($user_id_set);
        return $user_id_set;
        }
?>
<?php
$user_id_set = get_user_id();
while ($user_id = mysql_fetch_array($user_id_set)) {
    $cookie1 = "{$user_id["id"]}";
    setcookie("ptb_registrations", $cookie1, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */

}
?>

<?php include ('includes/send_email/reg_email.php'); ?>

<? ob_flush(); ?>
```

Assign session to variables :

```
$first_name = $_SESSION['first_name'];
```

mysql_* functions are deprecated use mysqli_* or PDO

You code is vulnerable to mysql_injection : use atleast `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: i did everything you said and its still not putting it into my mysql table, but im not receving any errors, it just says thanks for registering and doesnt insert the values :(

Comment: `echo $query;` add this line, before `mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database');` in page4 and see how your query is coming. please paste it here .

Comment: INSERT INTO ptb_registrations (ID, first_name, last_name, email, display_name, date_of_birth, contact_number, password, account_type ) VALUES('NULL', '', '', '', 'asdasd', '', '', 'adad', 'Member' )Error updating database